# <div> doesn't take the full height of the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the 4 colums with the class `.column` to be 100% of the page's height, but can't do it and I have no idea why.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  display: block;
}
#logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 15;
  padding-top: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 10%;
}
#menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu li {
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  /* variable width */
}
a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
a:link,
a:visited,
a:active {
  color: white;
}
.column {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
}
.clear-div {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">

  <div id="logo">
    CodePlayer
  </div>

  <div id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">JAVASCRIPT</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">OUTPUT</a>
    </li>
  </div>

  <div class="clear-div">

  </div>

  <div class="column" id="html">
    This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
  </div>
  <div class="column" id="css">
    This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
  </div>
  <div class="column" id="javascript">
    This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
  </div>
  <div class="column" id="output">
    This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
  </div>
</div>
```

I am a beginner and every advice on good web developement practices will be very valuable to me so if there's something that I could've have done better please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following CSS to each of your divs,for which you want the height to be 100% of page height:

```
 height: 100vh;
```

example:

```
<div class="column" id="html" style="height: 100vh;">
This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works but there's a little problem attached to it now it makes the divs take 100% of the pages height + 40 or 45 px added with the header element and now I have to scroll to get to the end of the page, anyway I can do this without scroling ?

Comment: you can change the height of each of your divs(columns) to 95vh instead of 100vh,and height of header to 5vh instead of 40px.

Answer (score 2):

percentages are with respect to parents and parent of column is `.header` which have 40px height 
thats why you have 40px height for you column

the problem you are solving is a bit difficult but you can do this

```
.column {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

see if that helps you

---

read about **vh** here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**. You also need to change your HTML structure a little.

Wrap all your 4 columns inside a parent div (in my case it is named as `.column-holder`) and give it a height using CSS `calc()` function. Like:

```
.column-holder {
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 45px); /* Total Viewport Height - Header Height */
}
```

Have a look at the working snippet below (*use full screen mode*):

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#header {
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    display: block;
}
#logo {
  float:left;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 15;
  padding-top: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 10%;
}
#menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align:center;
}
#menu li {
  display:inline;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
#menu a {
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:0 10px; /* variable width */
}
a:hover {
background-color: black;
}
a:link, a:visited, a:active {
  color: white;
}
.column {
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
}

.clear-div {
  clear:both;
}

.column-holder {
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 45px);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

 <title>CodePlayer</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

 <div id="header">

  <div id="logo">
   CodePlayer
  </div>

  <div id="menu">
   <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">JAVASCRIPT</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">OUTPUT</a></li>
  </div>

  <div class="clear-div"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="column-holder">
  <div class="column" id="html">
   This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
  </div>
  <div class="column" id="css">
   This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
  </div>
  <div class="column" id="javascript">
   This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
  </div>
  <div class="column" id="output">
   This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
  </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works best for my case, it's almost perfect but only one problem:
In the snippet it looks just fine  but in the real page the divs just stop at about 5px from the end of the page, any idea why it bahaves like this ?
How can I attach an image to explain better?

Comment: @Adi It would be great if you can host it on a server and give me the link, I can help you better in that case.

Comment: [![here.png](https://s23.postimg.org/6ib20l31n/here.png)](https://postimg.org/image/539hbv1yf/)

Comment: Sorry for this add infested image sharing server, it's the fastest one I could find, any suggestions for a better one ?

Comment: @Adi Calculate `height` of your header and then use the value of `height of #header` to subtract it from `100vh`. Like in my case the height of the header is `45px`, so I do it like: `.column-holder { height: calc(100vh - 45px); }`. Hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure is Wrong . if you wish to make Column take full page Height you will need to put columns out of header which is set to `height:40px;`

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  display: block;
}
#logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 15;
  padding-top: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 10%;
}
#menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu li {
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  /* variable width */
}
a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
a:link,
a:visited,
a:active {
  color: white;
}
.column {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
}
.clear-div {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">

  <div id="logo">
    CodePlayer
  </div>

  <div id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">JAVASCRIPT</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">OUTPUT</a>
    </li>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear-div">

  </div>

  <div class="column" id="html">
    This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
  </div>
  <div class="column" id="css">
    This column needs to be 100% of the page's heigh
  </div>
  <div class="column" id="javascript">
    This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
  </div>
  <div class="column" id="output">
    This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED ANSWER AFTER COMMENT (html structure in question was wrong)

You would probably want to restrict the overall height to 100%,  so use `height: calc(100% - 40px);` on `.column` as in the following snippet:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: block;
}
#logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 15;
  padding-top: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 10%;
}
#menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu li {
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  /* variable width */
}
a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
a:link,
a:visited,
a:active {
  color: white;
}
.column {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
}
.clear-div {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">

  <div id="logo">
    CodePlayer
  </div>

  <div id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">JAVASCRIPT</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">OUTPUT</a>
    </li>
  </div>

  <div class="clear-div">

  </div>
</div>
  <div class="column" id="html">
    This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
  </div>
  <div class="column" id="css">
    This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
  </div>
  <div class="column" id="javascript">
    This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
  </div>
  <div class="column" id="output">
    This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes but this will make my header element take the whole page and I don't really want this.

Comment: But your `.column` DIVs - hich you want to have 100% of the page height - are INSIDE the `#header` element. Either that is wrong in the HTML or your header needs to have 100% since its children have it. (?)

Comment: okay - I changed my answer again after your comment. But I only moved the columns out of the header. Now it should work the way you intend it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HEIGHT calc Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/) to get the height for column class. For this calc you need to header height and close the header div before the clear div and after the menu close div. Then you just write the column height something like this height: calc(100% - 40px) . 40px is your header height. 
Additional suggestions: remove the width and height you set for menu. So you will get better view on small screen. Also you don't need the column top:0 left:0; you can use this when you use position element. If you have any Question ask me in comment

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  display: block;
}
#logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 15;
  padding-top: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 10%;
}
#menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  

  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu li {
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  /* variable width */
}
a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
a:link,
a:visited,
a:active {
  color: white;
}
.column {

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  float:left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
}
.clear-div {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="header" class="clear-div">

  <div id="logo">
    CodePlayer
  </div>

  <div id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">JAVASCRIPT</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">OUTPUT</a>
    </li>
  </div>
 </div>
   
<div class="clear-div"></div>
  <div class="column" id="html">
    This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
  </div>
  <div class="column" id="css">
    This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
  </div>
  <div class="column" id="javascript">
    This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
  </div>
  <div class="column" id="output">
    This column needs to be 100% of the page's height
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer it helped me a lot!
But something very interesting happens when I do what you recomended me, in Atom's html preview it works like a charm but when I open with chrome no changes are shown. (I have saved the files) but when I try calc(100vh - 40px) it works really interesting.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `flex-layout` and achieve this with `min-height` property. For more info on flex layout read this ->https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
.fill-height-or-more {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  > div {
    border-style: solid; 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OboJdP